# Show that $\frac{xy}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}$ is not integrable on $S = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \colon 0 <|x|, |y|<1\}$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $S = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2  \colon 0 <|x|, |y|<1\}$ be a "punctured square." Consider the measure space $(S, \mathcal{L}_2, m)$. Here, $\mathcal{L}_2$ denotes the Lebesgue measurable subsets of $S$, and $m$ denotes Lebesgue measure on $S$. Define $f : S \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{(x^2 +y^2)^2}$.

Now, $f$ is clearly continuous. Hence $f$ is Lebesgue measurable on $S$, at least so long as we agree to define $f : S \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable $\iff$ for all $\alpha$, $f^{-1}((\alpha, \infty)) \in \mathcal{L}_2$  . So we are free to define the integral $\displaystyle \int_S f dm \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$. I would like to show that $\displaystyle \int_S f dm = \infty$.

I have not gotten very far with this problem, but I do have some thoughts. Perhaps I could try to construct a sequence of characteristic functions that lie below $f$ yet whose integrals diverge? That would do the trick. I have a sneaking suspicion that the proof will hinge on the fact that $\int_0^\epsilon \frac{1}{r^2}dr = \infty$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, but I'm not sure how to apply this yet.

Hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does your title match your function?  Which is it?

Comment: have you tried polar coordinates? Afterwards you should be able to split the integral into one small ball (thats probably where $\varepsilon$ comes from) and one larger ball that covers the rest of the domain

Comment: Hint: Your function is greater than $C {1 \over x^2 + y^2}$ for some constant $C$ on "most" of your domain.

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Comment: @Did--Thanks yes this answer makes perfect sense. I did edit the inequality you had for $f(x,y)$, since $x^2 + y^2 < 5x^2$ implies that the denominator $(x^2 + y^2)^2$ is less than $25x^4$.

Comment: @jtms88 And you shouldn't have (edited the denominator). Read better.

Comment: @Did Yes, I did read badly. Sorry about that and thanks for the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the triangle $T\subset S$ with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1/2,1/2)$, $(1/2,1)$. Thus, $T$ is defined by the inequalities $0\lt x\lt y\lt 2x\lt 1$. For every $(x,y)$ in $T$, $xy\gt x^2$ and $x^2+y^2\lt5x^2$, hence 
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\gt\frac{x^2}{(5x^2)^2}=\frac1{25x^2}.
$$
Thus,
$$
\iint_Tf(x,y)\mathrm dm(x,y)\geqslant\int_0^{1/2}\int_x^{2x}\frac1{25x^2}\mathrm dy\mathrm dx=\int_0^{1/2}\frac1{25x}\mathrm dx,
$$
which is infinite. Hence the function $f$ is not integrable on $T$, and a fortiori not on $S$ either.

Comment: Note that I do not understand why you say that *$f$ is clearly nonnegative*.

Comment: Yeah I edited out the statement. I was subconsciously thinking that we could solve the problem by restricting our attention to the first quadrant, where $f$ is nonnegative. Sometimes my mind gets ahead of me.

Comment: @Did, I'm a newbie to Lebesgue integral. *Fubini's Theorem* discusses about squared shaped areas. Could you say how *Fubini's Theorem* can be applied for *Triangular areas* ?

Comment: @FardadPouran No, Fubini's Theorem does not "discuss about squared shaped areas" only. I do not know what led you to this erroneous conclusion -- but this could make a good, separate, math.SE question.

Comment: Thanks. Someone has asked my question here and characteristic functions solve my problem ! :
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36558/questions-about-fubinis-theorem