# Does Fubini's theorem also apply for non-rectangular sets?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Fubini's theorem is usually stated as
$$\int_{X\times Y}f d(\mu \otimes \nu) = \int_X \int_Y f(x, y) d\mu(x) d\nu(y).$$

So it is always defined in terms of integrations over the whole spaces. I was wondering how to apply this for subsets though.

1.) So my first question is how I would use it if I want to integrate over some subset?

2.) My second question is if we can only use it for rectangular subsets of the form $A\times B$, with $A\in \mathcal{A}(X)$ and $B\in \mathcal{A}(Y)$ or if we can also use it for integrating over general subsets $C\in \mathcal{A}(X)\otimes\mathcal{A}(Y)$?
If the latter is also possible, how do we do it?

PS: There is a question related to this here [Questions about Fubini's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36558/questions-about-fubinis-theorem)
however the answers seem to contradict each other?

Comment: Apply the usual Fubini with $f$ being the indicator function of the set $C$. The choice of set can easily be encoded in the function. There are definitely some “curved” analogues of Fubini, but they’re not really relevant for what you’re asking about.

Comment: I cannot see any contradiction. Both answers say exactly the same thing, which is also the same thing as the above comment.

Comment: No one of the answers says you can apply right away and the other says you need to do change of variables and other transformations first. In any way I would like to see an answer, that gives me formulas that I can actually directly use...

Comment: Both answers that you pretend are different say to do the same thing. The only differences between them relate to the accepted answer being more general, while the other describes it in a limited, but more familiar, case. The idea is the same, and is as described in the accepted answer: you encase the region of integration in a rectangle, set the function to be $0$ outside of the region of integration, and use Fubini to integrate that. The other answer uses a characteristic function to accomplish the setting to $0$ outside. The accepted answer just defines the function to be $0$ there.

Comment: but how does that then really work? Can nobody write a proper answer of how these formulas look like then? This is all really unspecific...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C \in \mathcal{A}(X) \otimes \mathcal{A}(Y)$ be a general measurable subset. Write $A = \{x \mid  (x,y) \in C\}$ to denote the set of points in $C$ along the $x$-axis. For each $x \in A$, let $B(x) = \{ y \mid (x,y) \in C\}$ denote the "slices" along the $y$-axis for a fixed $x$. (Exercise: show that $A$ is $\mu$-measurable and $B(x)$ is $\nu$-measurable.)

The generalized version of Fubini's theorem is

$$
\int_{C}f(x,y) (\mu\otimes\nu)(\mathrm{d}x,\mathrm{d}y)
= \int_{A}\left[\int_{B(x)}f(x,y)\nu(\mathrm{d}y)\right]\mu(\mathrm{d}x).
$$